# Yarn test failing - Network request failed

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, cloud9-ide, create-react-app

I created a react project using `create-react-app` however when ran `yarn test` to see if the initial tests pass I get

```
TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js:436:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback.(anonymous function) (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:289:32)
    at invokeEventListeners (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:219:27)
    at invokeInlineListeners (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:166:7)
    at EventTargetImpl._dispatch (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:122:7)
    at EventTargetImpl.dispatchEvent (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:87:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:61:35)
    at XMLHttpRequest.abort (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:405:16)
    at Object.abort (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:315:13)
    at RequestManager.close (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/Document-impl.js:146:21)
    at Window.close (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:362:29)
    at JSDOMEnvironment.dispose (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js:44:19)
    at Promise.resolve.then (/home/ubuntu/wonderland/hackernews/node_modules/jest-cli/build/runTest.js:102:17)
```

I'm working in Cloud9 editor using ssh connected to my dev server (Ubuntu) hosted in AWS. Tests are working fine in my local machine (Ubuntu).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What version of react-scripts is it running?

Comment: I used version 1.0.7 of react-scripts. And I think it is the up-to-date version.

Comment: Are you able to ssh to your server from other Cloud9 projects, or is this the only one that's causing an issue?

Comment: Everything is fine. I can run and start my application the same with my local machine but when I'm in the point of running the test it fails.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's more of a cloud9 issue than a react issue. Have you confirmed that your ssh has the correct configuration for the workspace? Seeing if you can ssh into your server from a different, non-react cloud9 workspace would be a quick way to find out (or, at least, it might give you a better error message).

Comment: Thanks @DenTemple I will give it a try but I think there is some incompatibility with cloud9 in running jest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already solve my problem. I'm following a book entitled "The Road to Learn React" and I think that the one causing my error is the part where I `fetch` data from an external API. The book forgot to include an import for fetch which is this one:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'
```

Then, it solves my problem like a charm.